# How to get count of many to many relationship en php laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, model

hello i am working with models in laravel and i have the following structure and relationships:

Model Income

```
public function boxes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Box::class);
}
```

Model Box

```
public function incomes()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany(Income::class);
}

public function folders()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Folder::class);
}
```

Model Folder

```
public function box()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Box::class);
}
```

then I can get the count of boxes like this:

```
$income= Income::findOrFail($id);
$income->boxes()->count();
```

however I can't get the number of folders in a income

```
$income= Income::findOrFail($id);
$income->boxes()->folders()->count();
```

taking into account that between income and boxes there is a many-to-many relationship, how could I achieve this?

Comment: Which part of the documentation are you stuck on https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#aggregating-related-models

Answer (score 0):

You can define a new relation with `hasManyThrough`

Model Income

```
public function folders()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(
            Folder::class,
            Box::class,
            'income_id', // Foreign key on boxes table...
            'box_id', // Foreign key on folders table...
            'id', // Local key on income table...
            'id' // Local key on box table...
        );
    }
```

Then you can easily retrieve `folders` associated with an `income`

```
$income= Income::findOrFail($id);
$income->boxes()->folders()->count();
```

Comment: hello thanks for answering, income_id does not exist in the boxes table, this is a many-to-many relationship so there is a pivot table